# How to shorten a long list of if statements using another method, such as for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement

I am building a function in Python, and I have configured something that works, but it is very inefficient.

```
if board[0][0] == 1:
    detailed[1][2] = "X"
if board[1][0] == 1:
    detailed[3][2] = "X"
if board[2][0] == 1:
    detailed[5][2] = "X"
if board[0][1] == 1:
    detailed[1][6] = "X"
if board[1][1] == 1:
    detailed[3][6] = "X"
if board[2][1] == 1:
    detailed[5][6] = "X"
if board[0][2] == 1:
    detailed[1][10] = "X"
if board[1][2] == 1:
    detailed[3][10] = "X"
if board[2][2] == 1:
    detailed[5][10] = "X"
```

I know that I can use for loops to make this look nicer/more efficient, but become stuck almost immediately. So far this is what I have:

```
for x in range(3):
    for y in range(3):
        if board[y][x] == 1:
```

This handles the first part of each if statement, but not the detailed[][] = "X" line. There is a visible pattern, but I don't know how to use it to my advantage.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `detailed[2*y+1][4*x+2] = "X"`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the logic correct, this should give you what you want:

```
for x in range(3):
    for y in range(3):
        if board[x][y] == 1:
            detailed[x*2 + 1][y*4 + 2] = 'X'
```

Comment: You’re right. I edited it to swap them. I didn’t look hard enough at the original code part. It seemed more logical to put x before y ;-).

Answer (score 0):

No need for a for-loop, if you aren't married to it. Assuming you can work with numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np

board = np.array(board)     # if they aren't already numpy arrays
detailed = np.array(board)
mask = board[0:3, 0:3] == 1
detailed[1:7:2, 2:11:4][mask] = 'X'
```